# Proportion of primes that satisfies two legendre symbols?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a problem in regards to a paper that I am reading and I hope someone can guide me a little bit. Assume that $3s \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not a square, the paper states that the proportion of primes such that the Legendre symbols $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-3s}{p}\right) = 1$ is 1/4.

I'm not sure how he obtained this proportion, i understand for example:

1. That the proportion of primes such that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = 1$, is in fact 1/4.
2. The proportion of primes such that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = -\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) =1$ is also $ 1/4$.

Both of these propositions due to Dirichlet theorem.

Clearly, if $s$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}$ we have what is claimed. Otherwise, i know that by Cheboratev's density theorem the amount of primes such that $s$ is a square mod $p$ is 1/2. But here I am stucked, because I'm missing a way to connect this two ideas, i can naively think that then a half of the primes with the first condition plus a half of the primes with the second condition will lead to the proportion that I'm searching for (which adds to 1/4) but I am not sure if this reasoning is correct because some proportions of these primes might be "overlapping" or this cannot be the case?.

I hope someone can give me some ideas.

Comment: The set of such primes is a union of residue classes modulo $12s$ by quadratic reciprocity, so one can simply count the number of residue classes that work to see that the proportion is $\frac14$ in each case.

Comment: what paper, exactly

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin for the answer! but I am a little confuse by quadratic reciprocity can i get all the possible residue classes that works? because i will be using the jacobi symbol which doesn't represent in a good way the quadratics residues. But moreover inside these residue classes mod 12s how do you count 1/4 because for what I mean I know that for each residue class that works i have a proportion of $1/\phi(12S)$ but how do you get 1/4?

Comment: @WillJagy NON-ISOTRIVIAL ELLIPTIC SURFACES WITH NON-ZERO AVERAGE ROOT NUMBER
SANDRO BETTIN, CHANTAL DAVID, AND CHRISTOPHE DELAUNAY
page 16 more specifically

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.03095

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $a$ is not divisible by $p$. The Legendre symbol $(\frac{a}{p})$ is defined as $1$ if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, $-1$ if $a$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$, and $0$ if $a$ is divisible by $p$.

The proportion of primes that satisfy $(\frac{a}{p}) = 1$ and $(\frac{b}{p}) = 1$ is equal to the product of the proportions of primes that satisfy each condition individually, since the conditions are independent. Therefore, we have:

$$\frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{a}{p}) = 1 \text{ and } (\frac{b}{p}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}} = \frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{a}{p}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}} \cdot \frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{b}{p}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}}$$

By the quadratic reciprocity law, the proportion of primes that satisfy
$(\frac{a}{p}) = 1$ is equal to the proportion of primes that satisfy

$(\frac{p}{a}) = 1$. Therefore, the proportion of primes that satisfy $(\frac{a}{p}) = 1$ and $(\frac{b}{p}) = 1$ is equal to:

$$\frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{a}{p}) = 1 \text{ and } (\frac{b}{p}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}} = \frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{a}{p}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}} \cdot \frac{\text{number of primes }p\text{ such that }(\frac{p}{b}) = 1}{\text{total number of primes}}$$

Since $(\frac{a}{p})$ and $(\frac{p}{b})$ are either $1$ or $-1$, the proportion of primes that satisfy $(\frac{a}{p}) = 1$ and $(\frac{p}{b}) = 1$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. Therefore, the proportion of primes that satisfy $(\frac{a}{p}) = 1$ and $(\frac{b}{p}) = 1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

For example, let $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. The proportion of primes that satisfy $(\frac{2}{p}) = 1$ and $(\frac{3}{p}) = 1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, since there are 8 total primes (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19) and 2 of them (3 and 17) satisfy both conditions.